# ANOVA for ski race analysis (sports statistics)

Tags: anova, categorical-data, unbalanced-classes

I'm interested in analyzing data from cross-country ski races, to be able to answer questions like:

- How do particular individuals do in different types of races?
- How are individuals doing over the course of the season?
- In a hypothetical race involving racers A, B, C, etc. who would win?

The data I have to work with are results (skier name and time) from a bunch of previous races. Here are the issues:

1. Not every skier participates in every race.
2. There are two main "styles" of skiing (skate and classic). The a priori expectation is that some skiers do better in skate races, some in classic, and some are equal.
3. Races can be classified as sprint (short distances, very fast) or distance, and the "distance" races can be anywhere from 5K to 50K (marathons). Again, some people would be expected to do better at sprints, and others at medium distance or marathons.
4. Even races of the same style and distance (e.g., 5K skate) can have widely varying times, due to differences in snow quality, temperature, hilly vs flat terrain, etc.
5. Some skiers tend to be consistent throughout the season while others do poorly early on and get better over time.

For now I'm thinking of this in terms of just a single season. Most skiers have raced for many seasons, so there is more historical data out there, but I'm leery of using it because people's performance can vary a lot over time.

My statistics skills are a bit rusty (college courses are pretty far back in the rear-view mirror) but this seems like an unbalanced two-way ANOVA problem. I think what I want to do is to model the time for each skier (continuous dependent variable) in any race, based on a bunch of independent variables:

- racer (individual ID # - categorical)
- race (race ID # - categorical)
- race type 1 (1 = skate, 2 = classic - categorical)
- race type 2 (1 = sprint, 2 = distance - categorical)
- race distance (km, continuous)
- day of season (day number, continuous)

It's unbalanced because the number of racers in each race varies widely.

Does this seem like the right setup for this problem, or is there a better way?  Should I worry about interaction effects or not? How do I know if my data (results from prior races) are too sparse?

Comment: I suspect it is a bit more complicated than ANOVA. You probably need to look at regression models and probably have a mixed effects model with racer and race as random effects and the others as fixed.

Comment: To model changing form of different skiers across one or several seasons, you could model the random effects mentioned by @mdewey as an Ornstein-Uhlenbeck process.  To do this check out www.r-inla.org or the glmmtmb r-package.  With glmmtmb you can also specify a separate linear predictor for the dispersion of the response.  This might be of interest to model differences between the mean and the variance of race times between different races resulting from differences in snow conditions.